# Creating new relationships from path (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to build a new relationship from the allshortpath returned path.

```
$
MATCH (p1:Category {catName: "Main_topic_classifications"}), 
(p2:Category {catName: "Monarchs_of_the_Bulgars"}),
path = allShortestPaths((p2)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]->(p1))

FOREACH (s IN rels(path) | 
  MERGE (startNode(s))-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(ENDNODE(s)))
```

However, when I run this previous query I obtained this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, a property map or ')' (line 5, column 24 (offset: 248))
"      MERGE (:startNode(s))-[:NEW_REL]->(:ENDNODE(s)))"
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cypher language does not allow a node pattern to contain a function that returns the node (even though that would be very convenient).

This query (which first creates the node variables `s` and `e`, so that they can be used in node patterns) should work for you:

```
MATCH
  (p1:Category {catName: "Main_topic_classifications"}), 
  (p2:Category {catName: "Monarchs_of_the_Bulgars"}),
  path = allShortestPaths((p2)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]->(p1))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```